# Why is my custom UITableViewCell not showing?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've done custom UITableViewCells before without issue.. but I can't figure out what is going on with my current project.

Here's what I've done...

1. Create CustomCell.h (subclassing UITableViewCell)
2. Create an empty XIB and drag in UITableViewCell.  Set background to black.
3. Change class of UITableViewCell in Interface Builder to "CustomCell"
4. Import CustomCell.h in my DetailViewController
5. Modify `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"DO I GET HERE?");
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I would expect my tableview cells to show as black?  But they are still showing as white... any ideas?  Thanks!

**Update:**  Ok, turns out, it is loading the custom cell... I added a UILabel with some white text.  I couldn't see it, but when I highlighted the cell I could see the text was there.   So now the question becomes, why is the cell ignoring the black background I have set for the cell?

Comment: Don't you also have to change the owner in IB to your view controller?

Comment: Ignore my answer, my phone broke up the post.

Comment: First guess would be that you're loading `UIView` from a xib and you should set it as `cell.contentView`. Try setting: `cell.contentView = (UIView *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];` instead of `cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: rokjarc: I get assignment to read-only property error with that line

Comment: onnoweb:  I don't think so?  I'm looking at another example I have with this working and I don't see any references to file owner or anything in the XIB

Comment: In my example where this is working, the viewController is a UITableViewController and in this one I am using a ViewController with <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>.  That's about the only difference I can see between the two...  Also, this is in the detailviewcontroller of a UISplitViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to ignore the background colour I've set, so I just add a UIView to it with a background colour and that seems to work..

Comment: You can set the background colour in `willDisplayCell...`, that is the recommended place for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As for  why it's not black - I expect there is something obscuring your black - the likeliest candidate for this is the label background being white and not clear.

As well as point 3.

The attributes inspector (the 4th tab) needs to have the reuse identifier set to the identifier you are going to reuse (you use @"cell" in your question). I would try and use something a bit more specific - after all in some apps you might have many types of custom cells.

I think you also need to cast the topLevelObjects to (CustomCell*) thus

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"DO I GET HERE?");
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell*)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Tried setting reuse identifier as you suggested and casting.. but still getting the white cells :(

Comment: In the xib - Is the cell the first/only object? I can't think of anything else that might be wrong - the code you have is identical in form to that I've been using. Right click on the file's owner in the xib and check it's view is not set to anything - it shouldn't be etc.

Comment: Yep, cell is first and only.  I'm completely confused as well.  File's owner is not set to anything.   Does it make any difference that I'm using a UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> instead of a UITableViewController?  Also, this is the detailViewcontroller of a splitviewcontroller... Could that have anything to do with it?  I might be grasping straws here

Comment: Hey check my latest update to the question.. cell is loading, its just ignoring the background colour i've set?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your custom cell with the tableview

This needs to happen before that delegate is called:

```
[self.tableView registerClass: [CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```